# How do i fill combo boxes with data from mysql in visual c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, combobox

I've tried every single solution ive found on here and still cant get it to work

Currently all i get is a blank combo box regardless of what i change, can anyone see where im going wrong for title? (Yet to try price due to success with my titles combo box)
I'm trying to pull Title and Price out of my Game_Details table in the Aliena_Store MySQL database.

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.Common;

    namespace Aliena_Store
     {
     public partial class Form2 : Form
     {

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Game_List_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection
        "server=localhost;user=root;database=Aliena_Store
        ;port=3306;password=Blackie");

            string selectQuery = "SELECT Title,Price FROM 
            Aliena_Store.Game_Details";
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Game_List.Items.Insert(i, reader.GetString("Title"));
                i++;
             }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }


    }


    private void Game_Quantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Game_Price_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL may not be returning what you think

"Select Title * ...."  you probably didnt want that "*" in there.  Are you getting a number of blank entries or just no entries?

You do know your code is only running if you could change items on the drop down right?

Comment: I'm getting just a singular black slot in both game_list and price_list (price i expected to be blank currently but still)

Comment: If you want title and price put "Title,Price" as the 2 fields you want, or * if you wanted all of them.. a mix isnt going to help - plus you never close your connections etc.

Comment: So changed that, added a connection close and still pulling a blank. ill update my main code.

Comment: Are you sure theres actually data in there? when you debug it what do you get ?

Comment: PS it is normal to define which database you're in as part of the connection string ..

Comment: I filled my database table with 5 games so there should be data in the database and the database's name is Aliena_Store ill have a look at debugging

Comment: @Dusky I think i spotted your issue - your code only runs when you change the selected item for your game_list .. which it cant cos there arent any... you need to populate this in a more sensible location

Comment: ....I'm such a idiot... ~headbutts table~ been looking at this for 2 days with no clue what i did wrong.. thank you so much!

Comment: To be fair it looks like you had a few issues waiting to bite you anyway..  But hang your head in shame and we will never speak of it again :) pls mark as the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdownlist is Game_List, then you should try :

```
int i =0
while (reader.Read())
{
    Game_List.Items.Insert(i, reader.GetString("Title"));
    i++
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your query does not return any values, as pointed out by Dusky.
Did you use debug mode and breakpoints to check what values do you have in reader after query is executed ?